# How to get position of painted object in canvas

Tags: html, canvas

What i want to do is draw simple shape let's say rectangle by mouse and get directly from canvas his coordinates, height and width, it's possible?

I wrote this function:

```
function getImageProperties(image){
    var xMin = image.width;
    var xMax = 0;
    var yMin = image.height;
    var yMax = 0;
    var w = image.width, h = image.height;
     for (var y = 0; y < h; y ++) {
       for (var x = 0; x < w; x ++) {
           for (var c = 1; c < 5; c += 1) {
           var i = (x + y * w) + c;
           if(image.width* image.height * 4 != i){
                if(image.data[i] != 0){
                    if(x<xMin)
                        xMin = x;
                    if(x>xMax)
                        xMax = x;
                    if(y<yMin)
                        yMin = y;
                    if(y>yMax)
                        yMax = y;
                }
            }
         }
       }
     }
    var imgProp = {
        x : xMin,
        y : yMin,
        width: (xMax-xMin),
        height : (yMax-yMin)
    };
    return imgProp;
}
```

where

```
image = context.getImageData(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
```

but returned data is not same as i send to the drawning function :/

Comment: So you're trying to find the rectangle enclosing all of the non-black pixels?

Comment: OK. Let's say that i should look at 4th pixel for alpha. 
var i = (x + y * w) * 4 + 3; and image.data[i] > 0 but result of this is still inaccurate. For example when i draw rectangle in x,y = 5,5 my function reutrn 4,4.

Comment: yes, because the _width_ of the range `[min, max]` is `max - min + 1`, per my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks* like you're trying to find the rectangle enclosing all non-black pixels in the image data, but if so I can see a few minor issues, mostly with offset calculations.  Try this:

```
function getImageProperties(image){
    var xMin = image.width - 1;
    var xMax = 0;
    var yMin = image.height - 1;
    var yMax = 0;
    var w = image.width, h = image.height;
     for (var y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
        for (var x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
           var i = 4 * (y * w + x);
           for (var c = 0; c < 4; ++c, ++i) {
              if (c != 3 && image.data[i]) { // ignore the alpha channel
                 xMin = Math.min(x, xMin);
                 xMax = Math.max(x, xMax);
                 yMin = Math.min(y, yMin);
                 yMax = Math.max(y, yMax);
              }
           }
        }
     }

     return {
        x : xMin,
        y : yMin,
        width: (xMax - xMin) + 1,
        height : (yMax - yMin) + 1
     };
 }
```

That said, if you just drew the rectangle with a mouse it would be far easier to simply record the last two pairs of coordinates used in your mouse event handlers!

Comment: Thx, Alnitak. Not exactly, i want to use this function after resizing and rotating some object in canvas. Coordinates from mouse event will be unusable in this case.

Comment: Alnitak you function have one mistakes. It returns image properies (width, height, etc) - 1 because you should check only alpha channel. When I change this it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading the pixel colors using `getImageData`, but it really isn't such a good idea.

The best approach would be to store the positions and other data in an array outside the canvas.